# Ngrx, Ionic2 error "Return type of exported function has or is using name from external module.."

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ionic2, ngrx

I updated my project from Ionic2 Beta11 to RC0. I also updated ngrx/store to the latest version (2.2.1). Everything works fine, but I get an error in my reducers index.ts:

```
Return type of exported function has or is using name 'Post' from external module 'PathToPostInterface' but cannot be named.
```

I get the error in the following function:

```
export function getPost(id: number) {
  return compose(fromPosts.getPost(id), getPostsState());
}
```

has anyone experienced the same thing? How can I fix this problem? I suppose it has something to do with TypeScript, but since I'm relatively new to it I don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by importing 'Post' to index.ts.
But I don't know why this is solving it since 'Post' is not used anywhere in that file...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have declaration:true in tsconfig.json, I guess. To do it the compiler should know where to find it.

It works as expected in case I don't want to use it in other projects. Even though the return type of this function is correct, importing into a different project it will be any, so cannot be used, so I have to create reducer selectors in the target project instead in store project. Is there any workaround for it?